# using location in ember (how to lookup)

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

Trying to use [the Location class](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.4/classes/Location) with Ember 3.4.

How to instantiate/lookup/inject the `Location class` in my routes?

Writing this in a route file doesn't work:

```
import Location from '@ember/routing/location';

[...]

//in some action method
console.log(Location.getURL());

[...]
```

The result is:

```
getURL is not a function
```

This worked:

```
this.router.location.getURL();
```

Comment: Please have a look at `RouterService`.

Comment: Are you aware that `Location` is private API?

Comment: Thank you for pointing location is available as a property of router.

Comment: @Lux does this mean I should not use it? It's accessible from the router.

Comment: The `Location class` is private API and should not be used. The [`location`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.4/classes/RouterService/properties/location?anchor=location)  property on the router is public API and can be used, but probably not what you want. Similar the [`location`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.4/classes/EmberRouter/properties/location?anchor=location) property on the router. What you probably want and should use is [`currentURL`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.4/classes/RouterService/properties/currentURL?anchor=currentURL) on the router service.

Comment: I need to use location api (getUrl, replaceURL) but I see this doesn't work since link-to in the app are not updated.